# Is there a way to disable a UITabBarItem from reloading its first view?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I currently have an app that is a tab bar style app and supports rotation. Everything is great until you hit the tab bar when the device is in landscape and the original view is reloaded and placed back on screen. There is a lot of space and the overall appearance doesnt look good. Is there a way to disable this tab bar item from doing this?? Or if I could make it load a specific view by saying if in landscape push this instead that would work as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you could do, but before all that, did you thought using the Autosize /Autoplace feature on your objects when rotation occurs, you can even, if the GUI is to complicate, just load a 2nd view in horizontal mode.

**Chapter 5** of the **[Beginning iPhone Development](http://apress.com/book/view/1430216263)** book is all about this technique

Maybe you could improve your app just using Interface Builder Autosize properties on your objects

[alt text http://cl.ly/paX/content](http://cl.ly/paX/content)

before you actually hide/replace it.

What do you think?

Comment: I have the book. It wouldnt make sense however to rotate this because there are scrollviews and buttons. I thought about making a "default" screen that explains how the app works. That would auto rotate but I would really like to load my first view. Is there a way to make 2 views in one class AND tell the app if your orientation is landscape push the landscape version of the view when the tab bar is hit? I how if can be done for rotation but I dont know what to do in the case of the tab bar button.

Comment: this is kind'a messy, can you please add 2 images one that you currently have now and the other on what you would like to have so I can make you the code for that, as by your sentence and answer... I can't really figure it out. AutoSizing was a kinda nice point if you have easy GUI to handle, please provide me with 2 images so I can help you better. ty.

Comment: I did manage to figure it out with replacing it. A bit of work but it got the job done. Thanks for the help.